# Create rest api to fetch huge data from 50 tables from sql server in spring boot

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

There is 50 tables in ms sql server which named as Port1 to Port50 almost each tables having near about 55k data entries in it

Port table columns are as follows:

```
'SRNO'
'CDate'
'CompoNo
'ParameterName'
'PortValue'
'OP_ID'
'Event'
'CorrectiveActionID'
'Shift'
'Serialno'
'Customername'
'Heatno'
'Remark'
'Machine'
'Batch'
'MarkingData'
'Shim1'
'Shim2'
'JobNo'
'VendorCode'
```

as a result we want data in format below:

```
'Job No' (SerialNo)
'B/E Dia Top X'
'B/E Dia Top Y'
'B/E Dia Bot X'
'B/E Dia Bot Y'
'B/E Dia Top ovality'
'B/E Dia Bot ovality'
'B/E Thickness'
'B/E Notch Presence'
'B/E Top Face Perpendicularity'
'S/E  Flatness'
'S/E Dia Top X'
'S/E Dia Top Y'
'S/E Dia Bot X'
'S/E Dia Bot Y'
'S/E Dia Top ovality'
'S/E Dia Bot ovality'
'S/E Thickness'
'Oil Hole Presence'
'C.D.'
'Bend'
'Twist'
'B/E Weight'
'S/E Weight'
'Total Weight'
'Fixture_Temp'
'Comp_Temp'
'Status' (Ok/Not Ok)
```

serialNo is unique key (for us to fetch the data) through all the table  (somewehre in the tables serialNo is not mentioned properly) and others are the parameters

requirenment is to fetch the data from the all the tables with respect to the serialNo and show in the above format as result
and there is one table named as PortSetting, in PortSetting table limits are given for all the parameters

we have to compare the all the parameter portValue from the PortSetting table data and if the portValue is satisfied the condition UTL and LTL (from PortSetting) then set Status value as Ok otherwise Not Ok

I have tried below approach but because of huge data request will fail and
when i applied pagination then it will not fetch correct data because pagination limits the fetching the data from sql server

```
`@Data
@Getter
@Setter
public class DynamicPortDataDTO {
    private String serialNo;
    private List<Map<String, Object>> parameters;
}




@Service
public class DynamicPortDataService {

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DynamicPortDataService.class);

    public List<DynamicPortDataDTO> getAll() {
        List<DynamicPortDataDTO> resultList = new ArrayList<>();
        Map<String, DynamicPortDataDTO> resultMap = new HashMap<>();

        List<String> tableNames = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(
                "SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE' AND table_schema='dbo'",
                String.class
        );

        for (String tableName : tableNames) {
            if (tableName.startsWith("Port") && !tableName.equals("PortSetting")) {
                System.out.println("table Name 0000000000000000000000000 " + tableName);

                // Modify the query to include pagination
                String query = String.format("SELECT * FROM %s WHERE CDate > '2024-01-01' ORDER BY CDate", tableName);
                logger.debug("Executing query: {}", query);
                System.out.println("below query logger &&&&&&&&&&&&&&");
                List<Map<String, Object>> queryResults = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(query);

                for (Map<String, Object> queryResult : queryResults) {
                    String serialNo = (String) queryResult.get("SerialNo");
                    logger.debug("Processing serialNo: {}", serialNo);

                    DynamicPortDataDTO result = resultMap.get(serialNo);

                    if (result == null) {
                        logger.debug("Creating new result for serialNo: {}", serialNo);
                        result = new DynamicPortDataDTO();
                        result.setSerialNo(serialNo);
                        result.setParameters(new ArrayList<>());
                        resultMap.put(serialNo, result);
                    }

                    List<Map<String, Object>> tableDataList = result.getParameters();

                    String query1 = "SELECT * FROM " + tableName + " WHERE SerialNo = :serialNo";

                    NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(jdbcTemplate);

                    Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();
                    parameters.put("serialNo", serialNo);

                    namedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(query1, parameters, resultSet -> {
                        ResultSetMetaData metaData = resultSet.getMetaData();

                        if (resultSet.next()) {
                            do {
                                Map<String, Object> tableData = new HashMap<>();
                                for (int i = 1; i <= metaData.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                                    String columnName = metaData.getColumnName(i);
                                    tableData.put(columnName, resultSet.getObject(columnName));
                                }
                                tableDataList.add(tableData);
                            } while (resultSet.next());
                        } else {
                            logger.warn("No data found for serialNo: {}", serialNo);
                        }

                        return null;
                    });

                    // Update the parameters list in the resultMap
                    result.setParameters(tableDataList);
                }
            }
        }

        resultList.addAll(resultMap.values());
        return resultList;
    }


}`
```

Comment: Why would you want to fetch so much data over an API ? What are you trying to achieve

Comment: This code (and i use the term loosely) looks suspect. So, you first fetch all data from all tables based on some date, and then for each row you fetch the data again and then do "something" with it. Why not just fetch the data once using something like: `select * from table t where exists(select 1 from table t2 where t2.serialNo = t.serialNo and cdate  > '2024-01-01')` also, if you make a view out of all tables, you can simplify and remove your loop altogether